# Earned bounties layout is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, bounties

On both of my active sites the 'Earned Bounties' section header layout is broken:

[image]

It affects the header and the sorter.

(Tested on Chrome and IE, confirmed by others on Safari, FireFox)

Comment: Also affects Firefox 32.0.1

Comment: Okay. Good to know. It should affect Opera too, since it uses Chromium. Nicael reported FireFox to be affected too.

Comment: And Safari, yes.

Comment: The header seems to be missing the `<h1>` tags entirely, which is why it ends up looking like plain body text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The panel was mistakenly using the mobile layout. This is fixed and it will be out in the next build (#2568)

Comment: Ah, so that's what it was about. Did you also fix the event handler bug (#2 in my answer below) while you were at it?

Comment: Tested it and found it fixed.

Comment: The event handler issue seems to persist, so [I've reported it separately.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239549/mobile-user-profile-page-sort-selectors-stop-working-after-first-change)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be several bugs in one:

1. The title of the "bounties" section is missing the `<h1>` tags, causing it to be formatted as body text.  Fixing the code to generate proper `<h1>` tags should fix this.
2. The sorter works only the first time it's clicked.  This is a bug in the [client-side code](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/user.en.js), which attaches the event handler directly to the `<select>` element, and does not reattach it after the section is reloaded via AJAX.  The most straightforward fix is to replace this line in the `StackExchange.user.init` method:

   ```javascript
   $('.user-panel-subtabs select').on('change', function() {
   ```

   with:

   ```javascript
   $('.user-panel-subtabs select').live('change', function() {
   ```
3. If the sorter is changed several times between page reloads, its default value on subsequent page loads can get out of sync with the actual content shown in the section.  (This is normally masked by the previous bug, but becomes obvious if it's fixed.)  Apparently, what happens is that the section correctly shows whatever content was last requested, but the sorter instead remembers the *first* choice selected after the most recent page load.
4. If any actual bounties are shown in the section, there's an ugly gap between the header and the bounties.  This happens because the bounty list is formatted as a table, and the floating sorted pushes the table downwards.  Alas, fixing this part *properly* is likely to require redesigning the HTML structure entirely.

Anyway, I just wrote a quick client-side workaround for this bug for [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).  It fixes the first two sub-bugs above, by wrapping the title in `<h1>` tags and moving the event handler where it belongs, and sort of fixes the latter two issues by re-setting the sorter based on the section title, and by restyling the sorter to overlap the table instead of pushing it down (which can look ugly, too, but generally not as bad as the alternative).

For the curious, here's what the code for the first three fixes looks like:

```javascript
// fix #1: wrap header in <h1> tags
SOUP.hookAjax( /^\/ajax\/users\/panel\//, function () {
    $('body.user-page .user-panel .subheader > a').wrap('<h1></h1>');
} ).code();

// fix #2: make the change event handler live
var selector = '.user-panel-subtabs select'; var matches = $(selector);
if ( ! matches.length ) return;
$._data( matches[0], 'events' ).change.forEach( function ( h ) {
    if ( h.selector || ! /"div\[class='subheader'\]"/.test( h.handler.toString() ) ) return;
    $('body').on( 'change', selector, h.handler );
    matches.off( 'change', h.handler );
} );

// fix #3: sync the selector with the visible content
// XXX: this will only work on English sites, and may break if the title text is changed
matches.each( function () {
    var title = $(this).closest('.user-panel').find('div.subheader').text().toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( title.indexOf( this.options[i].value ) < 0 ) continue;
        this.options[i].selected = true;
    }
} )
```

The fix for the fourth issue is pure CSS, and looks like this:

```css
.user-show-new .user-panel .user-panel-subtabs.sorter {
    margin-bottom: -100%;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

If you'd like to test this fix, you can [install](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js) the unstable [development branch](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/tree/devel) of SOUP.  The less adventurous can wait for the next stable release (v1.24), which should include this fix.