# Mobile user profile page sort selectors stop working after first change

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web

The drop-down menus used to select user profile section sorting / display modes in the mobile view stop working after the first click:

> [image: Screen recording]

I've tested this both in Firefox on my desktop, and in Chrome on my Android tablet, and can confirm that it happens on both.

The problem is actually pretty simple: the event handler that makes the menu work is attached directly to the menu at page load time.  However, the handler itself reloads the entire section, *including the menu*, via AJAX, and does not reattach itself to the new menu.

The fix is also pretty simple: just replace this line in [user.js](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/user.en.js), in the `StackExchange.user.init()` method:

```javascript
$('.user-panel-subtabs select').on('change', function() {
```

with:

```javascript
$('.user-panel-subtabs select').live('change', function() {
```

or, better yet (to avoid the deprecated `jQuery.live()` method):

```javascript
$(document).on('change', '.user-panel-subtabs select', function() {
```

---

**Ps.** This bug is also masking another, related one: if the same section's sorting / display mode is changed more than once between page loads, on the next reload the section content will (correctly) match whatever was last selected, but the drop-down menu will show the *first* selection made after the previous page load.  This appears to be a server-side issue, so I cannot diagnose it further.

---

**Pps.** I've developed a client-side fix for the event handler issue, and a partial fix for the sync issue, which are included in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script as of version 1.24.  Alas, very few (if any) mobile browsers can run user scripts, so the practical value of the fix is limited.

Comment: This issue is fixed now.