# Sorting of badges on the profile page has 'gone'

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

It used to be possible to sort your badges by various mechanisms before.... but now, not? I remember three orders, newest, name, and class, if I recall.

Now I see:

> [image: Nothing?]

There used to be something there .... Right?

In the profile Summary tab, it's still in there:

> [image]

Comment: Even if it wasn't there before, it probably should be.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might share an underlying cause with [this recent SNAFU](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239382/earned-bounties-layout-is-broken). It looks as if some SE dev was a bit too careless when poking around the user profile page code lately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bunch of work done on the mobile website recently, that required many changes on the user pages, including the badges.

Inadvertently, the sort functionality on the badge page was dropped.

I've now added it back in and you will see it in the next build (rev 2014.9.22.1881, meta rev 2014.9.22.2591).

Answer (score 4):

There are two additional things to note here:

1. Tags have been capitalized, which makes this look a bit... itchy:

   > [image: Capitalized badges]

   Honestly, it really feels weird that 'Tumbleweed' is now written with a capital T. I could understand it for 'Stellar Question' but Tumbleweed...? Perhaps use `lowercase` for bronze, `Capitalized Text` for silver and `YELLCASE` for gold? :)
2. It is still possible to sort the badges on your summary page, but once you click 'view more', you're just... stuck in that ordering.

   > [image: Badges on summary page]

Comment: More to the point, you can still switch views "manually" by appending `&sort=recent`, `&sort=class` or `&sort=name` to the badge list URL. It's just the UI links to do that which are missing.